# Function with a variable number of parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I would like to know please how can I define a function that takes as much parameters as the user provides. For one parameter my function does the following:

```
def _more_data_(one_param):
    f = open(file,'w')
    f.write(str(one_param)+';\n')
    return
```

The function will eventually write all the input data the user provides in a a file names 'file'.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, yes it does. I should improve my searching skills. Thank you!

Comment: Marked as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this answers your question.

```
def _more_data_(*args):
  f = open(file,'w')
  f.write(str(args[0])+';\n')
return
```

Or you can do this to write every argument you pass.

```
def _more_data_(*args):
  f = open(file,'w')
  for i in range(len(args)):
       f.write(args[i])
return
```

Happy to help : )

Comment: The first code kind of makes the `args` useless...

Comment: Yep I know I did it and just for illustrations :).Hope it helped

Comment: It did help, thanks :)

Comment: No worries mate